# recursive find in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, recursive-query

I have this model and I want to get all children of this model with mongoose and show it one UI.
I try recursive functions but my problem is I cannot get back any object.

```
let postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:       String,
parent:     String,
children:   [String],
schoolId:   String
});
```

I try to recursive function like bellow:

```
findunderposts = function(post){
var result = [];
Post.findOne({
    _id:post
}).then(pfind=>{
    if(pfind.children){
        pfind.children.forEach(child=>{
            result.push(findunderposts(child._id));
        })
    }else {
        result.push(pfind);
        return result;
    }
})
};
```

i didnt get anything from this part when I did this:

```
                        resolve({ post:findunderposts(postId) })
```

Comment: anyway, a debugger should help

Comment: You miss a return in case you have children. After forEach, and you should push on then after call the findunderposts inside loop.

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko I try to console log everything:(

Comment: @Tzomas that's a recursive function, in the first round it has 4 children, in second call it gets null then return itself but it doesn't return:(

Comment: a recursive function return always, return iteration and in the last case, the base case, if you were updating a variable then you dont need return.